# matching numbers in sequence with regex

Tags: regex

I'm having some issues understanding this regex: `^(\d{1,2}).(\d{1,2})$`

I don't know why it will match `56207` from the following list:

```
8.12
23.14
24
56207
```

I want it only to match the first 2 numbers.

How can I change it so it will do that?

Answer (score 1):

Escape the dot since it a special regex meta character which means to match any character:

```
^(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})$
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.` means any character, also a middle digit (`2` in `56207`). If you need to match `.` you have to escape it with `\.`.

```
^(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})$
```